# Folding (collapse/expand) codes in Intellij (How does it look like Eclipse?)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I got to InteliJ from Eclipse. So, I am programming in Java (for Android) in InteliJ now.
I have problems with **FOLDING (collapse/expand)** style in IntelliJ.

This is a sample of **code folding** in Eclipse (**and I love it**) :

[image: eclipse code folding style]

and This is **code folding** in Intellij (or Android Studio) **and I hate it** :

[image: Intellij code folding style]

Is it possible to convert code folding style in InteliJ to Eclipse? (**Eclipse folding** is my target)

- I want to hide `@Override` or any annotations from all methods in IntelliJ
- I want to hide folded symbol `{...}` or move it in method name line in IntelliJ

Like this :

*(in following picture, I removed @Override manually. so,I've moved to manually  bracket `{` to the method name line.
)*

[image]

**Update 1 :**
I tried to solve my problem  in `(Intellij) File -> Settings... -> Editor -> Code Folding` , **but I could not solve**.

Comment: Not without writing a plugin, and even then I'm not sure if it's doable. Edit your code in Eclipse if it's that big of a deal, do everything else in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Richi nice question. +1 for that =)

Answer (score 2):

**For Android Studio:**

```
File --> Settings --> Editor --> General --> Code Folding
```

From that section you can select the way you want to fold your methods and inner classes etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by changing code formatter style.

**For Mac :**

> Eclipse -> Preference -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit

**For Window :**

> Window -> Preference -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit

Please check below links for more details.

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse

Comment: Thank you Chirag Raval, But I am working in Intelij and I wand change Intelij folding style to Eclipse folding style.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Eclipse`.
2. Click on the top tool bar and then click on `Preferences`.
3. On the left side of the box, expand `Java` option, expand `Code Style`, and click `Formatter`.
4. The active profile must be set to `Eclipse[built-in]`, you cannot edit this setting, so make a new one by clicking the `New...` button.
5. Enter your new profile name and click `OK`.
6. You will now be presented with the `"Profile 'name you set'"`box.
7. There are 8 tabs: `Indentation, Braces, White Space, Blank Line, New lines, Control statements, Line wrapping, Comments`.
8. Click on each tab and make the changes. **Dont forget to click Apply**.
9. Now to format the current document, click on `Source` from the menu bar, click `Format` or press `Ctrl+Shift+F`.
10. Job well done. =)

Comment: Thank you @Switch, But I working in Intelij (sorry for my bad question. i modified my question )